# PHPMyAdmin Crashing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I try to access on the of the tables in my database on PHPMyAdmin, it seems to crash PHPMyAdmin alltogether.

If I click on the table to view it I get a TON of this error:

```
Notice in ./libraries/DisplayResults.class.php#2644
 Trying to get property of non-object

Backtrace

./libraries/DisplayResults.class.php#2548: PMA_DisplayResults->_addClass(
string 'data hide ',
boolean false,
NULL,
string '',
)
./libraries/DisplayResults.class.php#3962: PMA_DisplayResults->_buildNullDisplay(
string 'data hide ',
boolean false,
NULL,
)
./libraries/DisplayResults.class.php#3222: PMA_DisplayResults->_getDataCellForNonNumericColumns(
NULL,
string 'data hide ',
NULL,
array,
array,
boolean false,
string 'PMA_mimeDefaultFunction',
string 'PMA_mimeDefaultFunction',
array,
boolean false,
array,
object,
NULL,
)
./libraries/DisplayResults.class.php#2852: PMA_DisplayResults->_getRowValues(
object,
array,
integer 24,
array,
array,
string 'grid_edit click2',
array,
string 'SELECT * FROM `keywords` ORDER BY `campaign_id` ASC ',
array,
)
./libraries/DisplayResults.class.php#4412: PMA_DisplayResults->_getTableBody(
object,
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1623: PMA_DisplayResults->getTable(
object,
array,
array,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1901: PMA_getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(
object,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
array,
boolean true,
string '3702',
integer 25,
NULL,
object,
array,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2107: PMA_getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(
object,
array,
string 'trafficcopter_db',
string 'keywords',
NULL,
NULL,
object,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
string '3702',
integer 25,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `keywords` ORDER BY `campaign_id` ASC ',
NULL,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1984: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'trafficcopter_db',
string 'keywords',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `keywords` ORDER BY `campaign_id` ASC ',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#216: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'trafficcopter_db',
string 'keywords',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `keywords`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

At the bottom I can "Ignore All", "Ignore", or "Report".

It doesn't crash MySQL, just PHPMyAdmin.

It makes it so when I try to access PHPMyAdmin I get a white error screen with

```
This page isn’t working IPADDRESS is currently unable to handle this
request. HTTP ERROR 500
```

If I wait a while I am able to access PHPMyAdmin again. 
This only happens on that one table.

EDIT:
I tried re-installing php my admin, and now any time I visit the PHPMyAdmin for this site I get this error:

```
This page isn’t working
IPADDRESS is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: re-install PHPMyAdmin

Comment: When I am trying to reinstall it I am getting an error as well

Comment: And now I inlstalled it without any errors, but when I got to it I get a This page isn’t working
165.227.111.103 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Did you uninstall the broken version properly before reinstalling?

Comment: sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
and then sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

Comment: I tried again and I just can't get it to install correctly