# Why does executing a count() return a PhpMyAdmin error with backtrace

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute the following command over PHPMyAdmin 4.8.4:

```
SELECT *, count(ref_id) AS c FROM `articles_test` group by ref_id order by c desc
```

This returns the following error message:

[image]

Followed by this error backtrace:

> Notice in ./libraries/classes/Display/Results.php#2488  Trying to get
>   property of non-object
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/classes/Display/Results.php#2389:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_addClass( string 'data hide ', boolean
>   false, NULL, string '', )
>   ./libraries/classes/Display/Results.php#3818:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_buildNullDisplay( string 'data hide ',
>   boolean false, NULL, ) ./libraries/classes/Display/Results.php#3071:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getDataCellForNonNumericColumns( NULL,
>   string 'data hide ', NULL, array, array, boolean false, array, array,
>   array, boolean false, array, , NULL, )
>   ./libraries/classes/Display/Results.php#2695:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getRowValues( , array, integer 24, array,
>   array, string 'grid_edit click2', array, string 'SELECT *,
>   count(ref_id) AS c FROM `articles_test` group by ref_id order by c
>   desc', array, ) ./libraries/classes/Display/Results.php#4287:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->_getTableBody( , array, array, array,
>   boolean false, ) ./libraries/classes/Sql.php#1738:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Display\Results->getTable( , array, array, boolean false, )
>   ./libraries/classes/Sql.php#2031:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable( , string
>   './themes/pmahomme/img/', NULL, array, boolean true, string '2554',
>   integer 25, NULL, , array, ) ./libraries/classes/Sql.php#2252:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Sql->getQueryResponseForResultsReturned( , array, string
>   'test', string 'articles_test', NULL, NULL, , string
>   './themes/pmahomme/img/', string '2554', integer 25, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, string 'SELECT *, count(ref_id) AS c FROM `articles_test`
>   group by ref_id order by c desc', NULL, ) ./import.php#736:
>   PhpMyAdmin\Sql->executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean false,
>   string 'test', string 'articles_test', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, string 'tbl_structure.php', string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, string 'SELECT *, count(ref_id) AS c FROM
>   `articles_test` group by ref_id order by c desc', NULL, NULL, )

I am running the following system:

> 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Datenbank-Client
>   Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id:
>   b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $ PHP-Erweiterung:
>   mysqliDokumentation curlDokumentation mbstringDokumentation
>   PHP-Version: 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Is this a bug, or might there be a problem with the db? No errors are visible, tables look OK.

Comment: Do simple queries work? like "SELECT * FROM articles_test LIMIT 1" ?

Comment: Maybe same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972998/phpmyadmin-crashing

Comment: Yes, everything else seems to work. I now upgraded to the newest version, but still the same error.

Comment: 4.8.4 is 11 days old. Maybe its a bug? Try downgrade to 4.8.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the MySQL version you are using. The query

```
SELECT *, count(ref_id) AS c 
FROM `articles_test` 
group by ref_id order by c desc
```

will not run on default settings in MySQL 5.7 and greater due to the default sql_mode only_full_group_by. The problem is that you are mixing the all columns notation (*) with an aggregate function. Older MySQL versions allowed this (erroneous) query, but MySQL 5.7 by default is more strict.

If you want to list all rows from articles_test with count for each ref_id (same value repeated for same ref_id's), use a subquery:

```
SELECT a.*, count(ref_id) AS c 
FROM articles_test a
  JOIN (
    SELECT at.ref_id, count(*) as refid_count
    FROM articles_test at
    GROUP BY at.ref_id
  ) q as q.ref_id=a.ref_id
```

Comment: I am runnning the following version: Server-Version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu). So this might be the issue. Is there another notation that will return all results and the counter?